# Jquery each - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, each

I have a function that uses each but the problem is that I want it runs or loops 14 times, but it loops more than 14 times until gives error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

As you see in the image below it doesn't stop at 14 and starts over again at 0 , 1 ,2  etc...

[image]

I have tried

```
 if(index = 14){
   return false;
 }
```

also i have try break;

At the moment my code that gives the error is this:

```
  var type = [];

  type[1] = $("#type_1").val();
  type[2] = $("#type_2").val();
  type[3] = $("#type_3").val();
  type[4] = $("#type_4").val();
  type[5] = $("#type_5").val();
  type[6] = $("#type_6").val();
  type[7] = $("#type_7").val();
  type[8] = $("#type_8").val();
  type[9] = $("#type_9").val();
  type[10] = $("#type_10").val();
  type[11] = $("#type_11").val();
  type[12] = $("#type_12").val();
  type[13] = $("#type_13").val();
  type[14] = $("#type_14").val();

  $.each(type, function( index, type ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + type );
  });
```

i hope that i can just loop with each function in the array and nothing more!
Thanks for the help.

Comment: typo, it should be `index == 14` - `=` is assignment operator.

Comment: That error means you've somehow created infinite recursion. The `each()` loop you've shown isn't going to do that, so the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Also note that array indexing is zero based

Comment: Index starts with `0`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: The problem maybe in different place in your code, you should post your whole function and your loop. $.each should never throw this error, you probably call same function inside your function (recursion) without guard.

Comment: Give the fields a class instead of ID and use `var type = $.map($(".type"), function(element) {
       return element.value;
    });` - assuming you have form fields

Comment: above code will work if you remove your typo with 'if' condition. may be there is some other error in your page.